# Why animating a div to move upwards and then right ends with a jump?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm learning animations, and trying to make a `div` (with an `input` inside it) move upwards and then right.

The upwards transition looks nice and smooth. However, the transition rightwards "jumps", and ends in a higher point (in relation to the previous state).

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```css
.container {
  top: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 5s 1;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 30%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `left` has no known starting place, so it has no known position to begin animation from. Try the following:

```css
.container {
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 5s 1;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 30%;
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input />
</div>
```